# javascript innerHTML print misplaced

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

```
<table class="privilage">
                <caption> These are the default users for institution </caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Users Name</th>
                        <th>User Id</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                         <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name='DefaultUser[]' value='' ><br></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name='DefaultUser_UserName[]' value=''></td>
                            <td><input type="password" name='DefaultUser_Password[]'></td>
                        </tr>


                <div id="New_User"></div>
                </tbody>
  </table> <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button"   name="Add_New_User" value="Add new User" onclick="addRow()"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The above HTML have a div named New_User, I asked the below javascript to print ussing innerHTML to that div, but it prints out elsewhere.

```
 function addRow()
 {
var d= document.getElementById("New_User");
d.innerHTML+="<tr><th><input type='text' name='DefaultUsers' value=''/> Manager<br></th><th><input type='text' name='UserName' value=''/></th><th><input type='password' name='Password'/></th></tr>";
}​
```

I just need to add those new row to the 'privilage' table.
Any Consideration and help are welcome. 
Thanks in Advance.

[Jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/abelkbil/QPY6b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually add new rows to your table without an extra Div inside it. You can use JS in-house functions to achieve this.
Also Please remove `<div id="New_User"></div>` from your **tbody**, This makes your DOM structure invalid.

Do this, Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/QPY6b/5/,

Add a new attribute id="tableID" to your table though!

```
function addRow() {
            var tableID = "tableID";
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "text";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            cell2.appendChild(element2);

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element3 = document.createElement("input");
            element3.type = "text";
            cell3.appendChild(element3);


        }
```

​

Comment: var tableID = "tableID"; should it terminate with ;

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML DOM structure is invalid, unfortunately. You can't put a `div` tag inside a `tbody` like you're doing. A `tbody` can only contain `tr` tags.

Give the id `New_User` to your `tbody` tag and your script will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is may be what you want.. http://jsfiddle.net/ztnMk/

```
<table class="privilage">
                <caption> These are the default users for institution </caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Users Name</th>
                        <th>User Id</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="New_User">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name='DefaultUser[]' value='' ><br></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name='DefaultUser_UserName[]' value=''></td>
                            <td><input type="password" name='DefaultUser_Password[]'></td>
                        </tr>
<!-- YOUR NEW TR GOES HERE... -->

                </tbody>
```

and here the JS:

```
function addRow(){
var d= document.getElementById("New_User");
d.innerHTML+="<tr><th><input type='text' name='DefaultUsers' value='Manager'/> </th><th><input type='text' name='UserName' value=''/></th><th><input type='password' name='Password'/></th></tr>";
```

}​

Hope this will help!

Comment: Please answer the question here, it's fine to have a link, but I shouldn't have to visit to even know what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

replace the div by a tr with an id and paste your innerHTML into that. Remove the tr tags from your inner html before doing so.

you may have to put 3 empty cells in your tr from the beginning; you can set the hight of your tr to 0, also from the beginning. Then after pasting your innerHTML in the tr you can remove the height as follows:

```
document.getElementById("myTr").style.height = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes like, Moved your div out of all tables,

```
<table class="privilage">
   <caption> These are the default users for institution </caption>
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Users Name</th>
          <th>User Id</th>
          <th>Password</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name='DefaultUser[]' value='' ><br></td>
          <td><input type="text" name='DefaultUser_UserName[]' value=''></td>
          <td><input type="password" name='DefaultUser_Password[]'></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 
<div id="New_User"></div> 
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="button"   name="Add_New_User" value="Add new User" onclick="addRow()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is adding new row at the bottom of first and before add user button. Please review this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPY6b/2/)

Comment: This too is goood. Thanks a lot